# Was JK Rowling inspired by The Legend of Zelda?

Tags: harry-potter, the-legend-of-zelda

There are some similarities, such as the sword of Gryffindor and the Master Sword, and the Deathly Hallows symbol, which looks similar to the Triforce.

So, is it possible for JKR to have been influenced by the videogame *Legend of Zelda*?

[image: Hallows Triforce]

Comment: Are you sure you've ever seen a picture of the Triforce?

Comment: I didn't mean exactly. I am going to edit that.

Comment: The [Sierpinski triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_triangle) looks more like the Triforce.  (The first step in generating it _is_ the common form of the Triforce, at that)

Comment: Other than both being triangular, they really don't have anything in common.

Comment: Comparing the film version of the Sword of Gryffindor and the Master Sword - there's no similarities other than being swords with hilts. The idea of the sword selecting the owner is probably more based on Excalibur than anything else.

Comment: Triangle symbology is... VERY common in human culture. Pyramids. Masons. Greeks. (list goes on forever)

Comment: JKR reverse-engineered all the books directly from equilateral triangle inspiration.

Comment: @GorchestopherH -  I quite liked the suggestion that JKR was just the frontman of a book-writing and film-making collaborative headed by senior execs at Bloomsbury and Warner Bros. The suggestion was that her writing was too prolific and her success came too easy for any real writer to achieve; Unemployed to billionaire in less than 5 years?

Comment: Leaving a comment because I can't access the source right now (www.jkrowling.com via the wayback machine), but there is a tidbit on JKR's old site that indicates at one time she like to play one certain video game -- I think it *might* have been Minecraft, but I could be wrong ... another game name is on the tip of my tongue and I just can't remember what it is. If I find it, I'll give an answer. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - Minesweeper, though she's since admitted (via twitter) to minecraft as well. Was Minecraft even around in the mid 2000's?

Answer (score 6):

Human beings have used symbols to communicate since, at least, the beginning of recorded history. Scientists can't explain how it is that we learn and understand language, except to say what parts of the brain do these things. The fact that these two symbols look similar is only in the triangle. I would not hazard a guess as to whether or not J. K. Rowling has ever played any of the Legend of Zelda games, however, I would say that it is highly unlikely that she used the Tri-force as her inspiration for the Deathly Hallows. Each of these symbols means something different in symbology and in canon.

### **The Deathly Hallows**

**Canon:** The Deathly Hallows is made up of a triangle, which represents the invisibility cloak, a circle which represents that resurrection stone, and the line through the center which represents the elder wand. When all three of them are held, it gives one mastery over death.

**Symbology:** Triangles represent balance and stability, but in this case, when coupled with a circle like this could represent unity for strength. The line splits both down the middle, symbolizing balance or duality, which gives way to the possibility of choice. Taking into account each element and what it means, it would probably support canon best by saying that the three make one whole that together are stronger than they would be alone. That is why they are drawn together, instead of separate.

### **The Tri-Force**

**Canon:** The Tri-Force is made up of one large triangle to represent the whole and the other triangles, one piece for power, wisdom, and courage each.

**Symbology:** This symbol is actually very much older than the Legend of Zelda series. Triangles, as I mentioned before, represent stability and balance. Symbolically, there are not just three triangles here, there are actually five. Multiple triangles like this represent unity through stability. The bringing of three together breeds balance. The concepts of trinities are nothing new, exempli gratia, the Holy Trinity, human beings being of mind, body and spirit, et cetera. Canon is probably supported best by saying that bringing the three triangles together makes a stronger triangle.

In closing, I would like to say that these two are obviously not the same. The triangle is not synonymous with Nintendo or with The Legend of Zelda and can be used by anyone for anything. Human beings are predisposed to interpreting symbols as more than just what they are. It's part of how we reason and part of how we communicate and form relationships between one instance of something and another. While the Tri-force and The Deathly Hallows are slightly similar, they are two completely different vehicles for two separate pieces of two completely different stories.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: I guess you didn't read the whole thing.

Comment: References for your symbology analysis?

Comment: I studied a great deal of material a few years ago. I read some books. I could find them and their names if you like. Of course, my post was long and I wanted for it not to be too long, so I gave a very simple and short analysis to keep the gist of the information that I was trying to convey.

Comment: @FuzzyMcNubNubs - The gist of your analysis is (as I understand it) that JKR may or may not have been influenced by Zelda but that the themes referenced are common to many genres. While this is interesting, the question was "was x influenced by y", not "is z a common theme"/

Comment: If you don't like my answer, then give him a better one.